# Learning Plates, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, composer-php, thephpleague

I've already installed composer and verified that it's running properly

this in my controller:

```php
//index.php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use League\Plates\Engine;

$templates = new Engine('/templates');

// Render a template
echo $templates->render('layout', [
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'name' => 'Jonathan'
]);
```

this is my layout:

```php
//layout.php
<?php $this->layout('template', ['title' => $title ]) ?>

<p>Hello, <?= $name ?></p>
<?
```

this is my template:

```php
//template.php
<html>
<head>
    <title><?= $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?= $this->section('content') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

this the error that i get:

> GET /templates/template.php - Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/finsoft2/Documenti/Playground/plates test/templates/template.php:6
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/finsoft2/Documenti/Playground/plates test/templates/template.php on line 6

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to Composer? And what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Are both `layout.php` and `template.php` in the templates folder? And the trailing PHP tag in `layout.php`, is that relevant? The error is because the templates file is not being rendered by the engine, but we don't have enough information to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is largely OK, apart from two small issues:

- The faulty closing tag in layout.php should be removed.
- The template directory you've entered in the constructor of `Engine` is an absolute path. The safest option is to use the `__DIR__` predefined constant to reference the path. This would result in:
  `$templates = new Engine(__DIR__.'/templates');`

But the reason you're seeing the current error message lies somewhere else: you're performing a GET request to /templates/template.php. You should be performing a request to index.php. When accessing the template file directly, the template engine doesn't exist and the interpreter doesn't know how to fill the variables.